# Pulling specific Parent/Child JSON data with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to pull specific information from a json file.

So far I have this:

```
# Import json library
import json

# Open json database file
with open('jsondatabase.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# assign variables from json data and convert to usable information
identifier = data['ID']
identifier = str(identifier)

name = data['name']
name = str(name)

# Collect data from user to compare with data in json file
print("Please enter your numerical identifier and name: ")
user_id = input("Numerical identifier: ")
user_name = input("Name: ")

if user_id == identifier and user_name == name:
    print("Your inputs matched. Congrats.")
else:
    print("Your inputs did not match our data. Please try again.")
```

And that works great for a simple JSON file like this:

```
{
  "ID": "123",
  "name": "Bobby"
}
```

But ideally I need to create a more complex JSON file and can't find deeper information on how to pull specific information from something like this:

```
{
  "Parent": [
    {
      "Parent_1": [
        {
          "Name": "Bobby",
          "ID": "123"
        }
      ],
      "Parent_2": [
        {
          "Name": "Linda",
          "ID": "321"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is that the actual structure of the json you are parsing?  It is odd because you have lists (json arrays) in there, but each list just has a single value...unneeded complexity.  Or do you have control of this format and this is notional?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that you might be able to pick apart.

You could either:

1. Make a custom de-jsonify `object_hook` as shown below and do something with it.  There is a good tutorial [here](https://realpython.com/python-json/).
2. Just gobble up the whole dictionary that you get without a custom de-jsonify and drill down into it and make a list or set of the results.  (not shown)

#### Example:

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

data = '''
{
    "Parents": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "Bobby",
            "ID": "123"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Linda",
            "ID": "321"
        }
    ]
}
'''

Parent = namedtuple('Parent', ['name', 'id'])

def dejsonify(json_str: dict):
    if json_str.get("Name"):
        parent = Parent(json_str.get('Name'), int(json_str.get('ID')))
        return parent
    return json_str

res = json.loads(data, object_hook=dejsonify)

print(res)

# then we can do whatever... if you need lookups by name/id,
# we could put the result into a dictionary

all_parents = {(p.name, p.id) : p for p in res['Parents']}

lookup_from_input = ('Bobby', 123)

print(f'found match: {all_parents.get(lookup_from_input)}')
```

#### Result:

```
{'Parents': [Parent(name='Bobby', id=123), Parent(name='Linda', id=321)]}
found match: Parent(name='Bobby', id=123)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized where I was going wrong with my code. Alternating between objects and arrays, figuring out the notation for that then putting it into logic.